# how to mask a URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, url-masking

I have a link displaying an image on my site which is from www.somedomain.com/image.jpg

How can I mask the domain so that it is www.mydomain.co.uk/image.jpg  ?

Would this be done using mod_rewrite?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will rewrite all calls from your domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you want to redirect all images, you can specify them by extension in the regex.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.somedomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+\.(?:jpg|gif|png))$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```